# Extract local endpoint info (IP address and port) when using ConnectEx + IOCP

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2, iocp

I am trying to create a client application that will use asynchronous IO using IOCP. I already did similar server application and it works correctly, however I can't find any information on how to extract local endpoint information from socket that is connected via `ConnectEx` API.

With server sockets, documentation states that info about both local and remote endpoints will be part of buffer sent to the `AcceptEx`. There is not a similar thing in `ConnectEx`. I tried also to extract local endpoint information through `getsockname`, however this returned some garbage values. I also tried to use `setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT, ...)` prior to calling `getsockname`, however the result was same as without it. Is there a way to do this or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

I also use `ConnectEx()` function and when the asynchronous `Connect` operation completes on `IOCP`, I normally call

```
::setsockopt(m_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT, nullptr, 0);
```

where m_Socket is my connect socket on a client side.
It works and then I can get the local name by the `::getsockname()` like this:

```
#define GoClearStruct(Struct)   memset(&Struct, 0, sizeof(Struct))

sockaddr_storage _AddrStorage;
sockaddr *_Addr = (sockaddr *)&_AddrStorage;
int _AddrLen = sizeof(_AddrStorage);
GoClearStruct(_AddrStorage);
if (::getsockname(m_Socket, _Addr, &_AddrLen) != SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    // extract the local name
}
```

It is difficult to find out the problem in your code, could you share more from it?
Did you check the return values of `::setsockopt()` and `::getsockname()`?